# Bootcamp - show bootloader by default

Tags: bootcamp

I have MacOS Catalina and Windows 10 Enterprise installed using Bootcamp, but it's a bit finicky getting the bootloader to show up (I know it's the option key, but it doesn't always work). Is there a way to get the Bootloader to display by default, and just boot into the default operating system after *n* seconds if no action is taken?

Comment: You can also select to make Windows the default from macOS System Preferences. You can make macOS the default from the Windows System Tray or Control Panel. You may need to run Apple Software Update to get this to work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such native feature. You can use a third-party bootloader like [rEFInd](https://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) to achieve what you want.

P.S. If holding Alt/Option on boot genuinely doesn't reliably show the Startup Manager for you, you should probably get that checked out.

Comment: There a non-Mac keyboards that work with with macOS, but the Mac will not read the alt/option key at startup.